# chart.js random weird problems

Tags: javascript, chart.js

this to me makes absolutely no logical sense.

my graph.js was working until it randomly just stopped after passing local storage as a prop. i refactored to make the prop passed in completely unrelated to the local storage... which still shouldn't matter.

for some reason every single number i put into the data field works EXCEPT when i put in props.score/number or ANYTHING reassigned that number. ive never seen anything like it. when i console log number is is 82. it is a number (it is blue in the console) yet when i put it into chart.js it just won't appear.

what the heck is going on?!

this feels like typing 2+2 into a calculator and getting 5. i literally have no idea i have now been trying to figure this out for maybe 4 hours with absolutely no answer. once again...

this error just happened randomly today my app was working fine prior to this...?!

did chart.js change something as of yesterday?
is this a random bug ?

i have never run into such a problem after backtracking for so long. makes no sense.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import './BreakDown.css'

const LineChart = (props) => {
  const number=props.score ***i am trying to get props.score into the chart js data point. 

  console.log(number) ****this console logs 82

  const newNumber=10+number
console.log(newNumber) ***this console logs 92

  useEffect(()=>{
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        responsive:true,
        data: {
            labels: ['X', 'IQ', 'X'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Your Score',
                data: [0,newNumber,0], ***no matter what i do plug in in either of these numebnrs here doesn't work. 
                backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,

            },
            {
                label: 'Average',
                data: [0, 100, 0],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        suggestedMin: 70,
                    suggestedMax: 160,
                    stepSize: 10
                    }

                }]
            }
        }
    });
  },[])
  return (
    <div >
    <canvas id="myLineChart" width="650" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
  )
}

export default LineChart
```

to make things EVEN more bizarre if i plug in newNumber into the chart it gives me 10 in this case EVEN though console.logging newNumber gives me 92... HUH?!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on the first render for me. I am not 100% sure from your description what you think is going wrong, but 1 problem I see is that useEffect will only run once due to the `[]` in the second parameter.

If your `prop.score` updates, `useEffect()` won't run again, which means your chart won't update.

The main change I did below was add `props.score` in the array for useEffect, this tells useEffect to run again if `props.score` changes. You can read more about this in the [useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Chart from 'chart.js';

const LineChart = (props) => {
    const number = props.score //***i am trying to get props.score into the chart js data point. 

    console.log(number) //****this console logs 82

    const newNumber = 10 + number
    console.log(newNumber) //***this console logs 92

    useEffect(() => {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart');

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            responsive: true,
            data: {
                labels: ['X', 'IQ', 'X'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Your Score',
                    data: [0, newNumber, 0],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,

                },
                {
                    label: 'Average',
                    data: [0, 100, 0],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 80, 235, 0.2)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, .5)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: false,
                            suggestedMin: 70,
                            suggestedMax: 160,
                            stepSize: 10
                        }

                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }, [props.score])
    return (
        <div >
            <canvas id="myLineChart" width="650" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LineChart
```